# Display content part in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I would like to be able to specify exactly where a ContentPart is rendered in a view.

For example, in my Content.Summary.cshtml I want to wrap my title and first image from the gallery (I'm using ZenGallery) in an anchor tag. I thought I would be able to do it like this but the gallery template is not rendered.

```
<a href="@Url.ItemDisplayUrl((IContent)Model)">
  <h2>@Model.ContentItem.TitlePart.Title</h2>
  @Display(Model.ContentItem.ZenGalleryPart)
</a>
```

But if I do the following then the gallery template (ZenGallery.Summary.cshtml) is shown along with all other parts.

```
@Display(Model.Content)
```

I understand that the recommended way to do this is probably using Placement.info, is that right? But this way makes more sense to me and would allow for more fine grain control of the end markup. How could I achieve the markup I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you a pretty good start on doing precisely what you want: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/07/31/so-you-don-t-want-to-use-placement-info.aspx

Comment: Thanks Bertrand, I had read your article but was hoping there was a simpler way. Basically, I have to include your `ShapeHelper` and then use `@Display(ShapeHelper.Find(Model, "Parts_ZenGallery_Summary"))` ?

Comment: Thanks, took a bit of tweaking but works now using `@Display(Util.ShapeHelper.Find((Orchard.DisplayManagement.Shapes.Shape)Model, "Parts_ZenGallery"))`

Comment: Is there a new way of doing this in orchard? I came across this but can't find claysharp anywhere anymore and I am guessing there most likely is a newer way after three years.

Comment: Clay has been replaced with a more specialized implementation of dynamic object.

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob but can you please expand on that answer or point me to the right direction. thanks for helping out.

Comment: Not really, sorry. I haven't had time to investigate how to adapt my code to the new model. All I can do is point you to those classes that implement DynamicObject.